# SQL Cube-ISO 8601 Calendar insert 445 months

Tags: calendar, ssas, iso, iso8601

I'm quite new to SSAS and currently building a cube. Everthing is OK so fart except that I need to use the ISO 8601 Calendar but unfortunately the built-in doesn't contains the months but only year,week,day.
What I want to achieve is to add months with 445 patterns like reporting months but using weeks,days,start/end of year of ISO 8601 calendar.

Is it possible to achieve this without editing manually the calendar table?

Thanks

John

Comment: I think it is possible to do that without manually editing the calendar table. But you probably will have to code the logic in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly! I've finally done something using this kind of logic:

```
WHEN [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]>=1 AND [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]< 5 THEN 'January,'+REPLACE(ISO_8601_Year_Name,'ISO8601 Calendar','') 
  WHEN [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]>4 AND [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]< 9 THEN 'February,'+REPLACE(ISO_8601_Year_Name,'ISO8601 Calendar','')
  WHEN [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]>8 AND [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]< 14 THEN 'March,'+REPLACE(ISO_8601_Year_Name,'ISO8601 Calendar','')
  WHEN [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]>13 AND [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]< 18 THEN 'April,'+REPLACE(ISO_8601_Year_Name,'ISO8601 Calendar','')
  WHEN [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]>17 AND [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]< 22 THEN 'May,'+REPLACE(ISO_8601_Year_Name,'ISO8601 Calendar','')
  WHEN [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]>21 AND [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]< 27 THEN 'June,'+REPLACE(ISO_8601_Year_Name,'ISO8601 Calendar','')
  WHEN [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]>26 AND [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]< 31 THEN 'July,'+REPLACE(ISO_8601_Year_Name,'ISO8601 Calendar','')
  WHEN [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]>30 AND [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]< 35 THEN 'August,'+REPLACE(ISO_8601_Year_Name,'ISO8601 Calendar','')
  WHEN [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]>34 AND [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]< 40 THEN 'September,'+REPLACE(ISO_8601_Year_Name,'ISO8601 Calendar','')
  WHEN [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]>39 AND [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]< 44 THEN 'October,'+REPLACE(ISO_8601_Year_Name,'ISO8601 Calendar','')
  WHEN [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]>43 AND [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]< 48 THEN 'November,'+REPLACE(ISO_8601_Year_Name,'ISO8601 Calendar','')
  WHEN [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]>47 AND [ISO_8601_Week_Of_Year]<= 52 THEN 'December,'+REPLACE(ISO_8601_Year_Name,'ISO8601 Calendar','')
```

And then used another query like this:

```
SELECT MIN(ISO_8601_Week) AS 'Month_date',Month_Name
FROM [Reporting].[dbo].[SSAS_Calendar]
GROUP BY Month_Name
ORDER BY Month_date
```

Month_Name being the created column and Month_Date returned the beginning of each month.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "Reporting Calendar" in Visual Studio. It can have 445 pattern. But for me it gives wrong numbers to weeks i.e. week gets the year of its Monday not its Thursday (as it should be according to ISO).

Choose "New dimension..." and then one of time dimension options.